# ios : Crash with log "error for object 0x173b74000: Freeing unallocated pointer" : Location Manager : Core Location

Tags: ios, objective-c

What my app does is gather location when user is driving around and uploads it to server when network is available, a car test drive app.

I am getting a SIGABRT on `checkColumn:existInTable:inDB:`  while the test drive is happening. Have log from Crashlytics stating "Freeing unallocated pointer".

```
#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18d8da014 __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d9a1460 pthread_kill + 112
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x18d84e3f4 abort + 140
3  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18d91ea38 _nano_vet_and_size_of_live + 330
4  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18d91fdb8 nano_free + 220
5  libsqlite3.dylib               0x18ee7f6f8 (null) + 2552
6  libsqlite3.dylib               0x18ee85924 (null) + 1204
7  TestDrivez                      0x100b812f4 +[SalesOfflineDBHandler checkColumn:existInTable:inDB:] + 4306817780
8  TestDrivez                      0x100b8114c +[SalesOfflineDBHandler checkDBForModifiedFields:] + 4306817356
9  TestDrivez                      0x100b80664 +[SalesOfflineDBHandler getDBPath] + 4306814564
10 TestDrivez                      0x100b7f6a8 +[SalesOfflineDBHandler updateTestDriveSyncStatus:forLead:] + 4306810536
11 TestDrivez                      0x100b8a58c +[SalesOfflineDataManager updateTestDriveInProgressDataOfflineWithLeadId:opportunityId:userId:latitude:longitude:timeStamp:speed:distance:isNew:andDBId:] + 4306855308
12 TestDrivez                      0x10013f544 -[AppDelegate updateTestDriveLocationToServer:] (AppDelegate.m:398)
13 CoreFoundation                 0x18e8a622c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
14 CoreFoundation                 0x18e8a5930 _CFXRegistrationPost + 400
15 CoreFoundation                 0x18e8a56ac ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 60
16 CoreFoundation                 0x18e914b9c -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1504
17 CoreFoundation                 0x18e7e7bf4 _CFXNotificationPost + 376
18 Foundation                     0x18f2ee6bc -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68
19 TestDrivez                      0x100b6f828 -[ABLocationManager updateTestDriveProgressToServer] + 4306745384
20 TestDrivez                      0x100b6f0d4 -[ABLocationManager locationManager:didUpdateLocations:] + 4306743508
21 CoreLocation                   0x19684e6fc (null) + 36216
22 CoreLocation                   0x196840ec4 (null) + 1036
23 CoreFoundation                 0x18e8ba160 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 20
24 CoreFoundation                 0x18e8b995c __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 288
25 CoreFoundation                 0x18e8b7c54 __CFRunLoopRun + 1976
26 CoreFoundation                 0x18e7e6048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
27 GraphicsServices               0x190269198 GSEventRunModal + 180
28 UIKit                          0x1947b8818 -[UIApplication _run] + 684
29 UIKit                          0x1947b3550 UIApplicationMain + 208
30 TestDrivez                      0x100264364 main (main.m:16)
31 libdispatch.dylib              0x18d7c85b8 (Missing)
```

Read that `__pthread_kill` means an exception is thrown and I am not handling it, but cant figure out from where.

The `checkColumn:existInTable:inDB` method shouldn't be causing it, cause its used through out the app and its working fine, everywhere else.

I am assuming this is something related to the location manager returning `NULL` object or it getting released.
I am getting the location from  `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` as `[locations lastObject];`

Noticed a `(null)` next to the name of binary `CoreLocation`.

Also in another thread in the crash log, I have this:

```
#11. com.apple.CoreLocation.ConnectionClient.0x170531260.events
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18d8bc1c0 semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x18d7a7784 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 112
2  CoreLocation                   0x196840d5c (null) + 676
3  CoreLocation                   0x196845f14 (null) + 1424
4  CoreLocation                   0x196845d08 (null) + 900
5  CoreLocation                   0x19688937c (null) + 66364
6  CoreLocation                   0x196886060 (null) + 53280
7  CoreLocation                   0x196885f94 (null) + 53076
8  CoreLocation                   0x1968871f8 (null) + 57784
9  libxpc.dylib                   0x18d9e0944 _xpc_connection_call_event_handler + 68
10 libxpc.dylib                   0x18d9de438 _xpc_connection_mach_event + 1448
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x18d795290 _dispatch_client_callout4 + 16
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x18d798d84 _dispatch_mach_msg_invoke + 328
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x18d7a3278 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 468
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x18d7981e4 _dispatch_mach_invoke + 652
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x18d7a3278 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 468
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x18d7989a8 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 652
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x18d7a3278 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 468
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x18d7989a8 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 652
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x18d7a42ac _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_item + 248
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x18d7aab0c _dispatch_kevent_worker_thread + 816
21 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d99d174 _pthread_wqthread + 948
22 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d99cdb4 start_wqthread + 4
```

So if anyone can clear my concerns regarding the below points, it will be of much help:

1. Am I wrong in assuming this is an issue related to LocationManager.
2. What does  `(null)` next to `CoreLocation` means in the crash log.
3. Is it possible for `didUpdateLocations` delegate call back array to contain NULL object.
4. How can I fix this.

Comment: Not easy to solve as the issue is mismanagement of memory, however where the actual error exists won't (generally) be anywhere near the exception.  However the crash will gives clues to the actual object that is being mismanaged.

Comment: @Droppy - Any tips or pointers on where, I should start looking will be much appreciated. I assumed it to be related to `LocationManager` since I saw `null` next to the `CoreLocation` binary. Guess I was looking at the wrong place.

Comment: I would suspect its in one of the parameters to `[SalesOfflineDBHandler checkColumn:existInTable:inDB:]`.